# "unique" validation rule not working?

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-validation

I can't get the 'unique' validation rule working. The validation passes and returns an SQL error instead.

My rule:

```
$validateRules = array(
'sku' => 'required|unique:items,sku|alpha_num|min:1);'
```

Returns SQL error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '123' for key 'items_sku_unique'

Could it be something wrong with my DB? (Table "items", column "sku" varchar(10) UNIQUE)

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to add sku with table name. Try

```
$validateRules = array(
'sku' => 'required|unique:items|alpha_num|min:1);'
```